# How to fix MBTiles Player on android use Nutiteq

Tags: java, android

I am new to android. I have converted map to mbtiles format. Now I need to create a sample application using nutiteq to display mbtiles on mobile. 
I try right click your project `Properties->JavaBuildPath->Libraries`....add the jar files from the `lib folder->Order and Export`....check the jars

```
try {
      MBTilesMapLayer dbLayer = new MBTilesMapLayer(proj, 0, 19, 2, "/sdcard/mymaps.mbtiles", this);
      mapView.getLayers().addLayer(dbLayer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```